Why is an iPhone not connecting on an otherwise okay WireGuard network that other devices can connect to?
There is an iPhone in my home that refuses to handshake properly with my VPN server, I have no idea what to do.
I have a home VPN Server (EDIT: which is also my DNS server) set up on a Debian box that chills behind an OpenWRT router, forwarding traffic for my devices and letting them have local access to all my home services. There are three peers currently in this VPN subnet that connect to the:

Debian Server
[Interface]
# Name = Debian Server
Address = 10.0.0.1/24, fdc9:281f:04d7:9ee9::1/64
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno3 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eno3 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <PRIVATE KEY>

[Peer]
# Name = Arch-Linux
PublicKey = <PUBLIC KEY>
PresharedKey = <PSK>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32, fdc9:281f:04d7:9ee9::2/64

[Peer]
# Name = Android
PublicKey = <PUBLIC KEY>
PresharedKey = <PSK>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3/32, fdc9:281f:04d7:9ee9::3/64

[Peer]
# Name = iPhone
PublicKey = <PUBLIC KEY>
PresharedKey = <PSK>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.4/32, fdc9:281f:04d7:9ee9::4/64



And connections as follows:

Arch-Linux Laptop: Connects fine with modified MTU under NetworkManager.
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.2/24, fdc9:281f:04d7:9ee9::2/64
PrivateKey = <PRIVATE KEY>
MTU = 1384

[Peer]
PublicKey = <PUBLIC KEY>
PresharedKey = <PSK>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = <public.ipv4.address.here:51820>
PersistentKeepalive = 5


Android Pixel 7: Connects great with the Android Wireguard app.
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.3/24, fdc9:281f:04d7:9ee9::3/64
PrivateKey = <PRIVATE KEY>

[Peer]
PublicKey = <PRIVATE KEY>
PresharedKey = <PSK>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = <public.ipv4.address.here:51820>


iOS iPhone 14: Only connects when on the local network but doesn't forward internet requests. If on data, the handshakes don't even make it to the router.
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.4/24, fdc9:281f:04d7:9ee9::4/64
PrivateKey = <PRIVATE KEY>

[Peer]
PublicKey = <PRIVATE KEY>
PresharedKey = <PSK>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = <public.ipv4.address.here:51820>



The settings on the iPhone are the same as the Android. From there I have tried:

Fiddling with the MTU.
Specifying a DNS server(EDIT: tested on wifi only)
Using Passepartout (Same results).
Changing the endpoint to use IPv6
Adding the VPN Server as one of the allowed IPs alongside 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0

I've run tcdump on both the server and the router and have noticed a couple things:

On home wifi, the iPhone is reachable by the server, pings and all.
On data, the router doesn't show any traffic reaching the wan interface. Like the iPhone isn't even routing the handshake properly.
If I resolve my home IP address on a browser in the iPhone, the Wireguard connection will resolve on data, but only temporarily.

It's almost like WireGuard isn't using the outgoing interface on the phone. I don't know, I'm reaching the edge of what I could possibly do to troubleshoot the issue. I'm hoping someone can read this and point out some apt thing I haven't considered.

probably not related, but have you tried toggling the randomized MAC address feature for wifi on the iphone?

I gave it a shot, but it didn't seem to change the result. The traffic still doesn't forward on Wi-Fi, even when the MAC randomization is set to Fixed or None.


It's not DNS.
It can not be DNS.
It was DNS.

I found a solution by assigning a remote DNS server(8.8.8.8) to the phone while on data, but not on wifi. One detail I forgot to mention about my set-up is that my VPN server also hosts my DNS server. After figuring digging a bit more, I set my BIND9 server to listen on the VPN network:
allow-query { localhost; private-network; 10.0.0.0/24; };
and add the DNS server to the phone:
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.4/24, fdc9:281f:04d7:9ee9::4/64
PrivateKey = <PRIVATE KEY>
DNS = 10.0.0.1 # Debian Box

[Peer]
PublicKey = <PRIVATE KEY>
PresharedKey = <PSK>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = <public.ipv4.address.here:51820>

Now the iPhone handshakes AND forwards traffic just fine on both data and wifi.
